# How to login into Onelogin via custom UI and redirect to a preconfigured APP

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml, onelogin, passport-saml

We need to be able to login to onelogin and redirect to an APP on clicking a button in our home page. We should also be able to send some custom params. We tried using passport-saml for this but we are getting

> The SAMLResponse ID was already processed

Any leads/documentation on how to proceed would be helpful.
Our passport code looks like

```
 passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
  {
    callbackUrl: '/app/agent-websites/onelogin/callback',
    entryPoint: entryPointUrl,
    issuer: issuerUrl,
    cert: cert,
  },
  function(profile: any, done: any) {
    console.log(profile);
    return done(null, profile);
  })
);
```